# ComboBoxEdit sorting changes underlying data

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In my `Grid` I am defining the `GridColumn.CellTemplate` of a `ComboBoxEdit` column e.g. 'UpdateReason' dynamically as follows. This allows me to create the `DataTemplate` dynamically for multiple different drop downs and bind the `ItemsSource` to the `ViewModel.ComboBoxValues` dictionary which contains the static list of drop down values for all rows.

It all seems to work ok when displaying the data first off, but when I click on the column header to sort the combo box column, the bound data values i.e. `RowData.Row.Order.OrderData[UpdateReason]` changes so the unique UpdateReasons are lost. The other columns move around in lock step with each other, but the text values on screen for this combo box drop down stays the same.

What am I doing wrong here? All of the `SelectedItem` text values are contained in the `ItemsSource` so it should be able to bind correctly. I have tried playing around with the `SelectedItem` `Binding Mode` i.e. `OneWay` etc but that doesn't seem to fix it.

```
public static DataTemplate GenerateComboBoxDataTemplate(OrderType orderType, string columnName, string viewName, int comboBoxCount)
    {
        string selectedIndexMarkup = comboBoxCount == 1 ? @" dxe:SelectedIndex=""0""" : string.Empty;

        string markup =
            string.Format(@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
                xmlns:dxe=""http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"" xmlns:Key=""ComboBoxEditDataTemplate"">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name=""PART_Editor"" dxe:IsTabStop=""False"" dxe:Focusable=""True"" dxe:ImmediatePopup=""True"" dxe:IsTextEditable=""False"" dxe:SelectAllOnGotFocus=""True""
                              dxe:ItemsSource=""{{Binding Path=ViewModel.ComboBoxValues[{0}][{1}], ElementName={2}}}"" dxe:SelectedItem=""{{Binding Path=RowData.Row.Order.OrderData[{1}]}}""{3} />
        </DataTemplate>", orderType, columnName, viewName, selectedIndexMarkup);

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(markup);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: You could try using `GridColumn.CellEditingTemplate` with your dynamic `ComboBox` for the `UpdateReason` Property. The selected value needs to bind to a simple property of your row-item. In the `CellTemplate` you can bind the your simple property to column `UpdateReason` (instead of dynamic `ComboBox` control). Maybe this works.

Comment: Can you tell, which type or class your ComboBoxItems are? The class shall implement `IComparable` for sorting. Also the ItemsSources of all ComboBoxEdits (for all rows) shall use the same/comparable class for its items.